# c++ interdependent class templates, pointer casting derived classes

Tags: c++, qt, templates, gcc, clang

Hello I'm writing a program that displays/shows and benchmarks different graphs. A graph consists of nodes and edges... So my problem is that I have two template classes (templates), which are bases for all derived classes

```
template <class Node>
class Edge
{
public:
    Edge() : startN(0), endN(0), price(0) {}
    Edge(Node *startN, Node *endN, int price) : startN(startN), endN(endN), price(price)
    {
        startN->toEdges.push_back(this); // PROBLEM HERE
        endN->fromEdges.push_back(this); // PROBLEM HERE
    }

    Node *startNode() const {
        return startN;
    }
    Node *endNode() const {
        return static_cast<Node *>(endN);
    }
    int getPrice() const {
        return price;
    }
    void setPrice(int price) {
        this->price = price;
    }

private:
    Node *startN;
    Node *endN;

    int price;
}; 


template<template<class> class EdgeTemplate >
class NodeBase
{
public:
    NodeBase() : nodeId(0), key(0), state(UNLABELED), prev(0) {}
    NodeBase(int id, int key) : nodeId(id), key(key), state(UNLABELED), prev(0) {}

    void addToEdges(EdgeTemplate<NodeBase> *edge) {
        toEdges.push_back(static_cast<EdgeTemplate<NodeBase> *>(edge));
    }

    int nodeId;
    int key;
    State state;
    NodeBase *prev; // prevous scanned

    QVector<EdgeTemplate<NodeBase> *> fromEdges; // start
    QVector<EdgeTemplate<NodeBase> *> toEdges; // end
};
```

errors occur in another template class:

```
template <template<class> class EdgeTemplate, class Node>
class DijkstraAlgorithm {
...
QVector<EdgeTemplate<Node> *> Edges; // the problem for derived classes
...
};
```

Clang:

```
error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'Edge<NodeBase<Edge> > *' with an rvalue of type 'Edge<DNode> *'
        startN->addToEdges(this);
                           ^~~~
```

GCC:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'QVector<Edge<NodeBase<Edge> >*>::push_back(Edge<DNode>* const)'
```

So as I understand the problem is that the derived class `DNode` (`class DNode : public NodeBase <Edge>`) can't be stored in the cointainer of base type `NodeBase<Edge>`... I've tried casting it but it didn't work.

Can someone please explain what am I doing wrong and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inheritance relations ships don't matter at all when looking at templates.

```
struct B {};
struct D : B {};

template<typename T>
struct C {};

C<B> *c = new C<D>; // error C<D> is completely different and has no relationship to C<B>

// you might as well say:
float *f = new char[50];
```

Consider:

```
template<>
struct C<B> {
    int a,b,c;
    int foo() { return a+b+c;}
};

template<>
struct C<D> {
    std::string s;
    std::string bar();
};

C<B> *c = new C<D>; // pretend it works.
c->foo(); // C<D> doesn't have a,b or c and doesn't have a method foo...
```

Maybe NodeBase should just take an edge type as a template parameter instead of the edge template.

```
template<typename Edge> struct NodeBase {
    QVector<Edge *> fromEdges;
};
```

Then DNode inherits from `NodeBase<Edge<DNode>>`

There's probably a better way, perhaps with a more direct use of the CRTP, but it's hard to say without seeing more of the current design.

Comment: that I didn't know and thanks for pointing it out(Inheritance and templates). The code works if I change addToEdges(EdgeTemplate<NodeBase> *edge) to addToEdges(void *edge), but that messes the benchmarking process (slows down the alg and times are incosistent). I'll rethink the design of the program and will look into CRTP, if that fails I'll consider your proposed solution. My main goal is not to repeat myself and easier maintenance. And thanks again for your reply, it was very helpful.

Comment: the proposed solution NodeBase<Edge<DNode>>, worked like a charm so your answer was very helpful and thanks again for the brief explanation on the templates and inheritance. Did try a couple of things but in the end I still ended up using your solution. Thanks!